# PHP 5 | Objects Passed by Reference / Value vs Copy on Write | When added as class property

Tags: php, oop, object, pass-by-reference, php-5.6

```php
class MyClass {
    // data going in
    private $in;
    // data going out
    public $out;
    // constructor
    public function __construct($obj0, $obj1) {
        $this->in = array('obj0' => $obj0, 'obj1' => $obj1);
        $this->out = array();
    }
    // method
    public function process() {
        foreach ($this->in as $key => $value) {
            $this->out[$key] = $value;
        }
    }        
}
```

**PRIOR KNOWLEDGE**

1. [Objects are passed by reference by default, but there are edge cases](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)
2. [PHP uses copy on write](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/zvals/memory_management.html)

**QUESTION**

1. Am I doubling the memory usage now since I have the objects in `MyClass->in` and `MyClass->out`?
2. If i use a method of `obj0` or `obj1` am I forcing a copy on write, even if it does not change any of the values of the properties of these objects?
3. Is the object still passed by reference when added as a class property?

Comment: Nothing is passed by reference in php unless declared otherwise using the `&` operator. `$foo =& $bar` would give `$foo` the same zval as `$bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the manual page you link to says, the statement "objects are passed by reference" is not a good description of what is happening. A better way to think of it is that the "value" of an object is a handle, pointer, or address to something that exists in a different space.

Whether you assign it to an object property, an array element, or a normal variable, this "value" remains the same, and changes to the object are visible wherever you look at them. Copying the value uses a few bytes (the size of the pointer) but doesn't duplicate the memory of the object itself.

As a final clarification, the "write" in "copy-on-write" refers to *modification* of an existing value, *after* copying it from one place to another. So writing `$foo = $bar`, where `$bar` is an array, will *not* duplicate the memory used by the array, but subsequently writing `$foo[0]=1;` or `$bar[0]=1` will, because the two copies need to be distinguished. This doesn't actually come into play in your example; if it did, it would be just the "object pointer" that was copied, so very little extra memory would be needed.

Comment: If I added a `get` method to `MyClass` and returned `MyClass->out->obj1` .. would that duplicate the memory used for that object?

Comment: @TT4M.C No, because you'd still only be returning the same object (another copy of the "value", which is just a pointer). If you returned an array, it would be a copy-on-write, like any other assignment. The engine doesn't much care about scope - parameters, return values, variables, and properties are all just "assignment" as far as the relevant code is concerned.